# Access VBA Setting Different Input Masks With Multiple Options and Values In a Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, input-mask

I have tables of different options that users can select for orders. With each option, I have different values that they can put in.

Is there a way that I can display different input masks at the same time?

For example, if the option is In-Hand Date, then it changes other option values to have the date format (Billing, Shipping, etc.), but I just want it to do the one option:

```
If Me.OrderOptionId = 20 Then
Me.OrderOptionValue.InputMask = "09/99/9999;0;/"
```

This is in the OnCurrent event. Is there a way I could set a qualifier after the mask for just the one option?

Here's the screenshot: 
[Access VBA Setting Different Input Masks With Multiple Options and Values In a Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3CFd.png)